# Как правильно построить индекс в БД для даты рождения?

Tags: база-данных, дата, индексы

Как правильно построить индекс в бд, для списка всех пользователей, у которых сегодня день рождение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте отдельное поле, в котором будете хранить месяц и день и постройте по нему индекс.